# Change tab item header background colour on loss of focus?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, tabitem

I want the background colour of my tab item's header to change when it looses focus. I was wondering what the best way to achieve this is, is it possible to achieve a purely XAML solution?

Comment: Tabs already change color (back to the default) when they lose focus.  Can you be more specific about what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the best way. I know this way.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TabControl Height="100" Name="tabControl1" Width="200">
        <TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1">
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="tabItem2" Name="tabItem2">
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks i didn't realise you had to do it through the styles like that, I thought there might be some way to keep the XAML in the local control node.

Comment: `Style` have reusable approach.